# Checkbox PropertyChanged Not Fired

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, mvvm

I have a MVVM application going on and trying to bind a checkbox within a datagrid but the Propertychanged event just doesnt fire. I have implemented INotifypropertychanged on the the viewmodel and the base class but still the property does not fire and the checkbox does not Update. I have tried all possible things like seting updatesourcetrigger=explicit or propertychanged but it just doe nto work. What I may be doing wrong?? I have no way of figuring out. The grid's datacontext is set to a ListViewCollection which is bound to an ObservableCollection.

```
                    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Tier1" Binding="{Binding Tier1Check,Mode=TwoWay}"></DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
                    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Tier2" Binding="{Binding Tier2Check,Mode=TwoWay}"></DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
                    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Tier3" Binding="{Binding Tier3Check,Mode=TwoWay}"></DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
                    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="DoNotUse" Binding="{Binding DoNotUseCheck,Mode=TwoWay}"></DataGridCheckBoxColumn>

                    <!--<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Tier1" Binding="{Binding IsChecked}"  />
                    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Tier2" Binding="{Binding IsChecked}" />
                    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Tier3" Binding="{Binding IsChecked}"/>-->
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

ViewModel...I have four checkboxes and the code is specific to making them mutually exclusive.

```
 public bool? Tier1Check
      {
          get
          {
              return Tier1Check;
          }

          set
          {
              Tier1Check = value;
              Tier2Check = false;
              Tier3Check = false;
              DoNotUseCheck = false;
              RaisePropertyChanged("Tier2Check");
              RaisePropertyChanged("Tier3Check");
              RaisePropertyChanged("Tier1Check");
              RaisePropertyChanged("DoNotUseCheck");
          }
      }
```

Comment: need full current code to take a look at it.

Comment: I see that your `Tier1Check` property gets and sets a member also called `Tier1Check`, which will likely cause a stack overflow exception since you are referring to the property itself.

Comment: I have a base class which defines the properties for the collection object whicv inherits the INotifyPropertchanged. I have defined the properties for the object also in the view model and raising notifychanged events. The datagrid is not able to fire any of these events. I cannot paste the code here because of the length constraint.

Comment: Can someone please assit? I desperately need this resolved asap.

Comment: Do you see Data Errors (binding errors) at runtime (see the Output window)? Can you step in debugging to RaisePropertyChanged lines?